# How to pass a Null as int type in SQL in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following SQL query. Please see line marked with ****. I would essentially like to pass that column as `INT` type but with null values for the first sub query so that I can insert integers into the column with the second sub query.

How can this be done?

```
select 
    fq.fk_spEngineerID, 
    fq.spQuoteID,
    fq.spOrderID, 
    fq.BU,
    fq.spProductTypeID, 
    fq.fk_spCompanyID, 
    fq.fk_spOfficeID
From 
    (Select 
         fk_spEngineerID, 
         spQuoteID,
         ****0 as spOrderID,**** 
         BU, 
         spProductTypeID, 
         fk_spCompanyID, 
         fk_spOfficeID, 
     From 
         QuotestatsSubQuery 
     Union All 
     Select 
         fk_spEngineerID,
         NULL as spQuoteID,
         spOrderID,
         BU, 
         spProductTypeID, 
         fk_spCompanyID, 
         fk_spOfficeID 
     From  
         OrderstatsSubQuery) as fq 
Group By  
    fq.fk_spEngineerID,
    fq.spQuoteID,
    fq.spOrderID,  
    fq.BU, 
    fq.spProductTypeID, 
    fq.fk_spCompanyID, 
    fq.fk_spOfficeID;
```

Comment: You want to change `0 as spOrderID` to `Null as spOrderID`, correct?  What happens when you make that change?  Is there a different outcome if you eliminate the `GROUP BY`?

Comment: correct problem is if I declare it as null in the first sub query it will not accept integers in the second sub query (error:data type mismatch) and no group by changes nothing

Comment: I don't understand why that happens.  This query runs without error and gives me `spOrderID` as an integer column: `SELECT sub.id, sub.spOrderID FROM (SELECT id, Null AS spOrderID FROM Dual UNION ALL SELECT id, CInt(1) AS spOrderID FROM Dual) AS sub GROUP BY sub.id, sub.spOrderID`

Comment: thanks alot the CINT cast did the trick thats what i was trying to do couldnt get correct formatting

Answer (score 1):

In case Anyone is looking for solution to similar problem the following solves the issue :

```
select 
    fq.fk_spEngineerID, 
    fq.spQuoteID,
    fq.spOrderID, 
    fq.BU,
    fq.spProductTypeID, 
    fq.fk_spCompanyID, 
    fq.fk_spOfficeID
From (
    Select 
        fk_spEngineerID, 
        spQuoteID,
        Null as spOrderID, 
        BU, 
        spProductTypeID, 
        fk_spCompanyID, 
        fk_spOfficeID, 
From QuotestatsSubQuery 
Union All 
     Select 
        fk_spEngineerID,
        NULL as spQuoteID,
        CINT(spOrderID),
        BU, 
        spProductTypeID, 
        fk_spCompanyID, 
        fk_spOfficeID 
    From OrderstatsSubQuery
) as fq 
Group By  
    fq.fk_spEngineerID,
    fq.spQuoteID,
    fq.spOrderID,  
    fq.BU, 
    fq.spProductTypeID, 
    fq.fk_spCompanyID, 
    fq.fk_spOfficeID;
```

Answer (score 0):

(1) `0 as column_name` will assume it is integer. To go an step ahead, you could `cast` it as Integer (Not sure hot to do it in msaccess).

(2) Your code is missing a comma before `0`. Let me know if you get any error running this.

```
select 
    fq.fk_spEngineerID, 
    fq.spQuoteID,
    fq.spOrderID, 
    fq.BU,
    fq.spProductTypeID, 
    fq.fk_spCompanyID, 
    fq.fk_spOfficeID
From (
    Select 
        fk_spEngineerID, 
        spQuoteID,
       NULL as spOrderID,
        BU, 
        spProductTypeID, 
        fk_spCompanyID, 
        fk_spOfficeID, 
From QuotestatsSubQuery 
Union All 
     Select 
        fk_spEngineerID,
        NULL as spQuoteID,
        spOrderID,
        BU, 
        spProductTypeID, 
        fk_spCompanyID, 
        fk_spOfficeID 
    From OrderstatsSubQuery
) as fq 
Group By  
    fq.fk_spEngineerID,
    fq.spQuoteID,
    fq.spOrderID,  
    fq.BU, 
    fq.spProductTypeID, 
    fq.fk_spCompanyID, 
    fq.fk_spOfficeID;
```

Comment: sorry was formating and deleted the , it is there, the problem is not the formating. I would like to insert a NULL there but have the collumn still be of INT type since the first sub query determines data types

Comment: I edited the code. Check now. If it doesn't work, check if you could `cast` null as Integer, not sure about it in msaccess.

Comment: you could also try swapping both union queries. Use `QuotestatsSubQuery` after union all.

Comment: Yes I know I can do that but if do that I will get a mismatch error on the second query trying to insert integers. Problem is that the first subquery determines the datatype so I would to cast it as a INT but insert nulls as values

Comment: Did you try running it? What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: yes, I get error 3464: Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Comment: Why not use an integer like `-999999` instead of null and later replace it with null?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do this:

```
select * 
from (
  -- ADD THIS SELECT/WHERE 1=0 TO DEFINE TABLE STRUCTURE
  select 
    fk_spEngineerID, 
    spQuoteID,
    0 as spOrderID,
    BU, 
    spProductTypeID, 
    fk_spCompanyID, 
    fk_spOfficeID, 
   from QuotestatsSubQuery 
   WHERE 1=0  -- THIS RETURNS NO RECS BUT YOU HAVE DEFINED TABLE STRUCTURE
   Union All 
   Select 
     fk_spEngineerID, 
     spQuoteID,
     NULL as spOrderID,
     BU, 
     spProductTypeID, 
     fk_spCompanyID, 
     fk_spOfficeID, 
   From QuotestatsSubQuery 
   Union All 
   Select 
     fk_spEngineerID,
     NULL as spQuoteID,
     spOrderID,
     BU, 
     spProductTypeID, 
     fk_spCompanyID, 
     fk_spOfficeID 
   From OrderstatsSubQuery
) as fq 
Group By  
  fq.fk_spEngineerID,
  fq.spQuoteID,
  fq.spOrderID,  
  fq.BU, 
  fq.spProductTypeID, 
  fq.fk_spCompanyID, 
  fq.fk_spOfficeID;
```

Hope this helps